# How to resolve inconsistent pixel sizes within a 16x16 texture in SDL-2 using C++?

Tags: c++, sdl-2

All the pixels in my texture have inconsistent sizes compared to each other that change based off of the size of the image its more apparent at smaller sizes
The file isn't the issue I've tried upscaling it

A video of the issue:

[image: A gif of my code running]

Code:

```
SDL_Texture* loadTexture(std::string path)
{
    //The final texture
    SDL_Texture* newTexture = NULL;

    //Load image at specified path
    SDL_Surface* loadedSurface = IMG_Load(path.c_str());
    //Create texture from surface pixels
    newTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, loadedSurface);

    //Get rid of old loaded surface
    SDL_FreeSurface(loadedSurface);

    return newTexture;
}
```

```
int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    SDL_Texture* loadTexture(string path);

    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Euka", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED && SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);

    //Initialize renderer color
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);

    //Initialize PNG loading
    int imgFlags = IMG_INIT_PNG;
    builderCreatureTexture = loadTexture("Assets/builderCreature.png");

    int xPos = 200;
    int yPos = 200;

    while (running)
    {

        //Initialize renderer color
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

        //Draw Here-----

        for (int x = -20; x < 20; x++)
        {
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
            SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
            creature.DrawCreature(renderer, builderCreatureTexture, xPos, yPos, globalSize + x);
            SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
            SDL_Delay(80);
        }
        //-----Draw Here

        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect? If the texture is to be scaled to, say, 123 pixels, it is impossible to have all 16 pixels of a texture scaled up to the same size. You need some sort of anti-aliasing to achieve the impression of equally-scaled pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a result of [nearest-neighbor sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling). If you want to avoid that, you have multiple options:

- only draw the image at sizes that are multiple of the original (n times bigger, with n an integer)
- specify a different sampling method for the texture with [`SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY)
- use [`SDL_RenderSetLogicalSize`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/SDL_RenderSetLogicalSize)
- roll your own sampling, potentially with anti-aliasing and other things ([see also: pixel-art scaling algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel-art_scaling_algorithms))

Example of using `SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY` for a texture:

```
SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY, "1");
newTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, loadedSurface);
// maybe reset to the default value
//SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY, "0");
```

I have never used `SDL_RenderSetLogicalSize` but my understanding is that you can do the same call to `SDL_SetHint` to specify what sampling mode the renderer will use for presenting.

If you write your own sampling code, you can render your original image to a target texture with [SDL_SetRenderTarget](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/SDL_SetRenderTarget) (making sure you use the `SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET` and `SDL_RENDERER_TARGETTEXTURE` flags), and then render that to the screen.